# Primefaces p:dialog keeps reopening

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My p:dialog keeps loading on and on, I need it to appear only once. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
    <h:body style="background: url('img/background/teste/brushed_alu.png')!important" onload="dialogAtivacao.show();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("j_username").focus();
    });
    </script>

    <p:dialog id="dialogAtivar" header="Ativação de empresa"  showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop" resizable="false"
              widgetVar="dialogAtivacao" modal="true" closable="true" rendered="#{sessionScope['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message == 'ATIVACAO'}">
        <ui:include src="pages/ativacao/AtivacaoEmpresa.xhtml"/>
    </p:dialog>
    ...
```

The button:

```
  <p:panel  styleClass="panelBotaoLogin" >
        <h:commandButton id="saveButton" action="#{login.doLogin()}" value="  Entrar" styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only botaoEntrar"/>
  </p:panel>
```

The login() in LoginBean :

```
    public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {
           ExternalContext context =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
           RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password);
           dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

           return null;
     }
```

I have one customAuthenticationProvider that returns 'ATIVACAO' when the database is empty, so I need open this dialog to insert data, but it keeps reopening(closes and immediately reopens).

Comment: What does "on & on" mean here? The dialog loads on page load? It refuses to close? Or it closes and immediately reopens? What is supposed to trigger the dialog normally?

Comment: Hi kolossus, it closes an immediately reopens. Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the trigger component of the dialog here for context

Comment: Is there any point in your view where you have `dialogAtivacao.show()`

Comment: In <h:body> onload="dialogAtivacao.show();"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `<h:body onload="dialogAtivacao.show();"/>` translates into *when the `<body>` tag of the HTML is loaded, display the popup*. The `<body>` tag will be reloaded when a full page reload of the view takes place
2. `<h:commandButton id="saveButton" action="#{login.doLogin()}" value="  Entrar" styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only botaoEntrar"/>` is going to trigger a full page refresh everytime the button is clicked.

Together, it becomes, *everytime I click this button, reload the entire page and show the dialog as a result*

Use an ajax command component instead:

```
 <p:commandButton id="saveButton" action="#{login.doLogin}" value="  Entrar" styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only botaoEntrar"/>
```

This way, an ajax request is triggered and the `onload` is triggered only once

Comment: Rather than using the `onLoad` function and do the ajax workaround, the `visible` attribute of the dialog should have the same expression as the `rendered` attribute. Then he can do a full page refresh without worrying about the dialog popping up, once the "database is not empty anymore".

Comment: @Manuel, that works too, but it appears to be a login page and I presume OP wants to display the dialog on opening the page. Using the `visible` attr will result in an extra validation parameter to check if the page load is a fresh request. Either one works anyways. You can post an implementation of that